# How to create a dataframe from a nested list of multiple common elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have ***any*** nested list, for example

```
A = [[120, 'Date1', 1.03], [120, 'Date2', 1.04], [120, 'Date3', 1.02], [240, 'Date1', 1.06], [240,'Date2', 0.98],
     [240, 'Date3', 1.04], [381, 'Date2', 1.03], [381, 'Date3', 0.85]]
```

The first element of each sub-list is the stock number, the second the date, and the third a corresponding value. I want to create a dataframe where the column headings are the stock number, row headings are the date and the elements are the corresponding (third element) values. I am not directly sure on how I would do this. I want to form something like this:

```
      120     240    381
Date1 1.03    1.06   NaN
Date2 1.04    0.98   1.03
Date3 1.02    1.04   0.85
```

But I want to form this for ***any*** size nested list, so I can't just type in each variable for the dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by constructor and then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A).pivot(1,0,2).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
        120   240   381
Date1  1.03  1.06   NaN
Date2  1.04  0.98  1.03
Date3  1.02  1.04  0.85
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert your list to a dict and then build a DataFrame directly.

```
d = {}
[d.setdefault(e[0],{}).update({e[1]:e[2]}) for e in A]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

        120     240     381
Date1   1.03    1.06    NaN
Date2   1.04    0.98    1.03
Date3   1.02    1.04    0.85
```